# What windows C IDE can I use that will use gcc to compile and let me insert breakpoints just like Visual Studio would for C#?

Tags: c, gcc, ide

What windows C IDE can I use that will use gcc to compile and let me insert breakpoints just like Visual Studio would for C#?

I have searched Google and cannot find anything more recent that 2005.

I'm just getting back into C since graduating and would like a non MS IDE that uses GCC, but that's a versatile as Visual Studio.

The thought of having to use GDB command line is not too appealing right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I successfully used Eclipse with C/C++ plugin. Matter of fact I prefer it to VS. You can download it [from here](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) it's a real beaut. If you do JNI it's simply indispensable since you can setup your project to do both C/C++ and Java

Answer (score 1):

Dev-C++ http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html
GPL license
Uses GCC

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans http://www.netbeans.org/features/cpp/index.html

Answer (score 0):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is another free C++ IDE for Windows/Linux/MacOSX. GPL3 license.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [Insight Debugger](http://sources.redhat.com/insight/) that is a lightweight Tk frontend to GDB by RedHat.

It adds a convenient GUI to call stack display, breakpoints, watches and memory display (non exhaustive list).

As it is in Tk, it both supports GNU/Linux and Windows (and probably MacOS X). For MinGW users, there is even a [MinGW package](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Other/UserContributed/insight/) to install it.

Once installed, you just add the `-w` setting to the command line to start the GUI: `gdb -w`

Answer (score -1):

ddd

you could found it on the "development" menu.